# display animated gif while running a sub

Tags: vb.net

How do i keep an animated gif running while my app is running a sub.
The whole UI is blocked so I've tried displaying it in another form but i get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

- Use a `BackgroundWorker` (example below)
- Rather use an indeterminate progress bar if you can, but this depends on technology used.

Example on BG Worker:

```
Private wrkDeploy As New BackgroundWorker()

Private Sub wndMain_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    AddHandler wrkDeploy.DoWork, AddressOf wrk_DoWork
    AddHandler wrkDeploy.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf wrk_RunWorkerCompleted
End Sub

Private Sub wrk_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    ' Hide Gif and start normal UI process again
End Sub

Private Sub wrk_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    ' Do all heavy work here
End Sub

Private Sub btnFilter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ' Show GIF and disable whatever you need to
    wrkDeploy.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Comment: What if all the heavy work is done by instantiating classes, and then starting threads for methods within those classes?  It is impossible to instantiate classes and start methods in those classes as threads within the DoWork subroutine(?)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you
>   to run an operation on a separate,
>   dedicated thread. Time-consuming
>   operations like downloads and database
>   transactions can cause your user
>   interface (UI) to seem as though it
>   has stopped responding while they are
>   running. When you want a responsive UI
>   and you are faced with long delays
>   associated with such operations, the
>   BackgroundWorker class provides a
>   convenient solution.

- [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)
- [Multi-threading with background
  worker](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet875.htm)
- [BackgroundWorker Demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/GUI/BackgroundWorkerDemo.htm)
- [How To Update Controls Using
  BackgroundWorker in VB.NET](http://vbnotebookfor.net/2007/09/24/how-to-update-controls-using-backgroundworker-in-vbnet/)

Comment: so i guess that i should make the sub run into a different thread rather then the animated gif. this is gonna take some re-writing of my app.

Comment: Anything done in the doWork of a background worker runs on a worker thread and leaves the UI thread alone. You can use RunCompleted to determine when the process is over, or ReportProgress during. Its quite the handy class.