# Animated GIF in Winforms

Tags: vb.net

I have used animated GIF in my application.  Actually there is a process that takes quite long and I wish to show something to the user to show progress.
I have put a picture box and put animated GIF.  It is visible property is set to false.
When user clicks on Save button, its visible property is set to true but animation does not show up.

Please advise what could be the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165735/how-do-you-show-animated-gifs-on-a-windows-form-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251731/display-animated-gif-while-running-a-sub

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the `Image` property when you set the `Visible` property to true.